# Open Form as ShowDialog But Close Initation Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is there any way to do the following, other than hiding then closing the hidden form later?

Mainform opens SecondForm as show dialog, i need to Open ThirdForm from SecondForm while closing SecondForm while keeping third form acting as "showdialog" on the MainForm?

Comment: you are going to have to describe what you are trying to accomplish a little better.

Comment: not sure how to i have a main form that stays open unless program is closed, there is a button on main form that opens second form using .showdialog so that is the only form that can be accessed.  within second form i need to open thirdform while closing secondform and  maintaining thirdform as a showdialog against main form so user cannot access mainform.

Answer (score 2):

When you show SecondForm(), pass in MainForm() as the owner to ShowDialog():

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sf As New SecondForm
        If sf.ShowDialog(Me) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            ' ... do some processing in here ...
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now, in SecondForm(), you can then set the owner of ThirdForm() to that of SecondForm():

```
Public Class SecondForm

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Dim tf As New ThirdForm
        tf.ShowDialog(Me.Owner)
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What does this line do?
Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK

do i have to worry about closing the me.hide() somewhere???

Comment: Setting DialogResult() is what allows execution to return to the ShowDialog() line that initially displayed that dialog.  That value is actually returned to ShowDialog() and you can check it to see if "OK" was returned.  If you return "Cancel" then your code can skip processing.  I'll update the code with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply open the third form from the main form as soon as the second form returns a dialog result

You also might want to look at MDI this gives you more control over what the user can and can't do.

Answer (score 0):

After trying Idle_mind suggestion it was still giving me problems going back and forth between forms continously showing them as .showdialog.   I solved my problem just like tinstaafl suggested.  I wish i would have got his message before a couple hours of trying different methods before coming up with this one.

When i close each form, i set a boolean flag in the main form. then i call a sub that is in the main form to show the next form as showdialog from the main form.  i use the flag which triggers logic in the form im loading whether or not to bind data from datatable so i can edit it.

sorry with all those forms i know it gets confusing.  to sum it up, close the dialog form (me.close), set flag so calling code knows what to do once the showdialog code is satisfied.